# Returning array to show in the html ANGULAR

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm not sure how this is done in Angular.
i have this mapped item

```
currentSuper?: any[];


this.currentSuper = response.builder?.superintendents?.filter((x) => x.id === 
this.builderSuperintendentId);
```

response.builder.superindentents returns

```
 [0:{id:'', firstName: '', lastName:''}, 
  1:{ id: '', firstName:'', lastName:''}]
```

the index number is throwing this off since currentSuper looks like this:

```
 [0:{id:'', firstName: '', lastName:''}]


<span class="text-secondary">Superintendent:</span><span class="mx-2">{{ 
order.value.currentSuper?.firstName }} {{ order.value.currentSuper?.lastName }}</span>
```

Where firstName is null now. I cannot do order.value.current[0].firstName either. so how to i get this data to actually render correctly?

Comment: currentSuper is an array so use ngFor syntax to iterate over it in the template. See https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives. I suggest making your types stricter too. Can you remove the optional of `currentSuper?: any[];` by assigning initial value `[]` and make `any` a type e.g. `type SuperIndentent = { id: string, firstName: string, lastName: string }`

Comment: i did change to       <div class="mx-2" *ngForOf="let currentSuper of order.value.currentSupers">? {{ currentSuper.firstName }} {{ currentSuper.lastName }}</div>
however it is just empty now on the UI side

Comment: *ngForOf is the wrong syntax, it's *ngFor - see the link. If you want to see the data you're trying to render as a debugging step stick `<pre>{{ order.value.currentSupers | json}}</pre>` before this div

Comment: thanks!! i got with the ngFor. also didnt need the order.value.currentSupers and just needed to have it as  let currentSuper of currentSupers

Answer (score 0):

Because it returns an array, you'll need to "grab" an item from the list, or render all the filtered items.

Take a look at the following examples that uses `itemList` as an array of items.

Grab an item (not recommended) using the index:

```
<div>
  {{itemList[0].id}}
</div>
```

Render all items using `ngFor`:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemList">
  {{item.id}}
</div>
```

Another option is to use `find` instead of `filter` so that it returns an object instead of a filtered array.
To me, this seems like what you're looking for

```
this.currentSuper = response.builder?.superintendents?.find((x) => x.id === 
this.builderSuperintendentId);
```

In the html you can just render the `currentSuper`:

```
<div>{{ currentSuper?.id }}</div>
```